# Accessing Cosmos data from widget

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I managed to persist context data in Cosmos. However, I don't know exactly how to access that information from a widget in the Mashup section of Fi-Lab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not direct integration between Cosmos and WireCloud. We are working on it (see the corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/29) for more information of the progress).